# Visual Studio Code window is not appearing

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10

I've encountered a very strange bug with Microsoft Visual Studio Code. I've been using VSCode for a few months now and never had this issue. When I open VSCode, the window just doesn't appear. The app is definitely open, because when I hover over the icon on my taskbar I can see what is being displayed in the app:

[image: VSCode is installed and a window is open]

Unfortunately, when I click on it, the window does not appear.... I've uninstalled and reinstalled, deleted cache, tried older versions and nothing has worked. Has anyone else encountered this and fixed it? Any advice?

Comment: Do you anything wrong in the vscode's log?

Comment: @ZhaoYi I dont know... Where can I find them?

Comment: It depends on the OS. You can search on `electron log` location on the OS you are using. In windows, it should be located under user local directory somewhere

Comment: @ZhaoYi i found my electron/logs directory, but it was empty. Funny enough, the bug went away.... and I think what caused it was Spotify. Spotify is also written on the electron.js framework, and could have screwed something up... I am also developing something with the electron js framework, so that could be the culprit too.

Answer (score 5):

I had something similar. It appears that the window is just off-screen. I've used my DisplayFusion display manager - to move windows to center/top where I could handle it myself. I expect it'll also work using `<Win> + <←>`  (maximize window to left side of screen).

Comment: I selected vs code from task list and hit <Win> + arrow keys but it did not show up. But I noticed something changed in the right side of my screen. Almost the size of the vertical scrollbar. I tried to drag it and it is vs code.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

- hover over VSCode icon in taskbar
- right click on it
- click on `"New Window"`
  That should do it.

[image: VSCode]

Comment: In my case that simply creates another window that I cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue went away when uninstalling the GlassIt-VSC extension. I tried modifying the opacity of the window and then it disappeared. I highly suggest you try uninstalling this extension.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had connected HDMI cable but due to power off my monitor was off, but when I disconnected hdmi cable; VS code visible on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with a plugin called [GlassIt](https://github.com/hikarin522/GlassIt-VSC/) while I was playing with a property called `"glassit.alpha"` somehow it went to `1` *(possibly I changed it accidentally)* and nothing showed up. *(here's an image where you can slightly see that I set alpha to `20`)*

[image: GlassIt alpha:20]

what i did was to just edit the `%appdata%\..\Roaming\Code\User\Settings.json` and set `"glassit.alpha": 1,` to 255

***UPDATE [I just realised there was already an answer I didn't see while I was writing this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62194804/11465149)***

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue during a remote desktop session and could bring the VSC window back via hitting F11 (via the onscreen keyboard in my case, since the F11 key on my keyboard was being captured by the host system).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a dual monitor setup, and the laptop was in clamshell mode. However, the laptop's built-in monitor was recognized as a third monitor, and VsCode was going there.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens after unlocking your screen it may be a setting in the windows display settings.

1. disable the windows display window handling:
   On Windows go to **System->display**
   Uncheck **the Remember window locations based on monitor connection**
   Uncheck **minimize windows when a monitor is disconnected**
2. find your application:
   Now select your VSCode window in the task bar and hit **F11** to maximize it.
   It should show up now.
   Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer since no one was helping.
Go to view.
Click solution explorer.
It should show the name of your project.
Click the small arrow at the beginning of the heading of your project.
Click source files.
Click yourproject.cpp.
Thank you.